# React issue on heroku when trying to reload the application, white screen

Tags: reactjs, heroku

The following error can be seen in the console when I try to reload the application on url.com/settings/devices, or anything with 2 sub routes I'm not sure what to issue is as it can not be replicated via localhost.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`
`main.1982b69e.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`
`manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^v16.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "browserslist": "^4.16.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^2.2.0",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.14.0",
    "react-promise-tracker": "^2.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-spinners": "^0.11.0",
    "react-toastify": "^8.0.2",
    "retry-axios": "^2.6.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Edit 1:

I've figured out that if I change the homepage in package.json to the url of my react application it fixes the issue, but I would like to find a "one shoe fits all" solution as I don't want to have to keep changing the homepage whenever I change the host platform.

Edit 2:
Figured out I can just set the package.json `"homepage": "/",` to get it to work as I wanted it to work.

Comment: When you build the project it offers an option to run the production build locally. Is that working? Can you also share the code of your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

set the homepage value in package.json to "homepage": "/",

- Begin with / to resolve from the root directory
- Begin with ./ to resolve from the current directory
- Begin with ../ to resolve from the parent directory